# How to capture click event for mobile on froala editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, froala

I have used this "'froalaEditor.click': function (e, editor, clickEvent)" to capture click event on Froala editor and it works fine on desktop and laptop but it is not capturing `click event` on mobile. Is there any other event to capture click event for mobile and iPad?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `touchstart` event for that:

```js
$('selector')
    .on('froalaEditor.touchstart', function (e, editor) {
    })
    .froalaEditor();
```